# how to change only some polygons style in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to let two sets of polygons behave as different layers, allowing to toggle the visibility of the layers independently. For example, when adding polygons from a geojson where their is no 'rgb' property I would like not to have to redefine the style for already drawn polygons.

I tried to not specify any return value for the polygons I don't want to change but it leaves the polygons with the default of google maps style in spite of their initial style.

```
var mapFrame = frames.getAtcMap(index);
// load the geojson
var file = "Council_Districts_2016.geojson";
$.get(file, function(data){
    var geojson = GetParsedForGoogleMaps(data);
    mapFrame.googleMap.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
    mapFrame.googleMap.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        if(typeof feature.getProperty('rgb')==="undefined"){
            return {
                fillColor: "white",
        fillOpacity:0,
        strokeColor:"blue",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2.5,
        zIndex:11
            };
        };
    });
});
```

I understand `setStyle` redefines the style of the whole map but is their anyway to redefine the style only of a set of the polygons?

Comment: @duncan I posted more of the code around but I'm not sure how to define "Polygon" in `Polygon.setOptions`.  Would very much appreciate a snippet showing how to use setOptions on something imported in geojson

Comment: Yeah I was on the wrong track, I deleted my previous comment.  Your code certainly seems similar to the examples given at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling around I've found mainly two possibilities.

## Using different layers

The more general and permanent solution. It simply defines a new independent layer for this second set of polygons. It is a good example on how to define multiple layers on a google map:

```
// global name of the layer to allow later reference
var layerCouncilDistricts = {};
function addOnTopCouncilDistricts(elem){
    // identification of the map in my multiple maps environment
    var index = elem.id.replace("addCouncilDistrict","");
    var mapFrame = frames.getAtcMap(index);
    // construct the new layer
    layerCouncilDistricts = new google.maps.Data(mapFrame);
    // attach it to a google map
    layerCouncilDistricts.setMap(mapFrame.googleMap);
    // load the geojson
    var file = "Council_Districts_2016.geojson";
    $.get(file, function(data){
        // parse the geojson
        var geojson = GetParsedForGoogleMaps(data);
        // add the geojson to the layer
        layerCouncilDistricts.addGeoJson(geojson);
        // set the style of the layer
        layerCouncilDistricts.setStyle(function(feature){
                return {
                    fillColor: "white",
            fillOpacity:0,
            strokeColor:"blue",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2.5,
            zIndex:11
        }});
    });
}
```

## For temporary changes

The second method is fine for temporary changes but does not separate this set of features from the others. One can use [`foreach()` of the data class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) to review all features and override the style. In my example something like:

```
// examine each feature
mapFrame.googleMap.data.forEach(function(feature) {
  // is feature to be changed
  if(typeof feature.getProperty('rgb')==="undefined") {
    // override existing style for this feature
    overrideStyle(feature,{
      fillColor: "white",
      fillOpacity:0,
      strokeColor:"blue",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2.5,
      zIndex:11
    });
  }
}
```

It works great and allows to further interact with the layer completely independently of other items.